# Margin on background image in CSS

Tags: css

I have a background image on a div, the size of the div is set to that of the image, However, I am unable to remove a margin that appears the left. See CSS below;

```
.faders-image {
  background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed; 
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  right: 0rem; 
  bottom: 0rem;
  margin: 0; 
  border: none;
  padding 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.50;
  z-index: 8; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a live preview, e. g. at JSFiddle.net.

Comment: And what if you add `background-position: left top;`?

Comment: Have you set `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } ` ? This removes all margins and paddings of the DOM elements unless specified otherwise.

Comment: You wrote `padding 0;` insteed of `padding:0;` maybe that's your problem

Comment: The -webkit prefix has not been needed on opacity in 200 years. Maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem with the page left margin , you can use the following style.

```
.faders-image {
  background-image: url(heart-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed; 
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0rem;
  margin: 0; 
  border: none; padding 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.50;
  z-index: 8;
}
```

I have changed the style `right: 0rem` to `left: 0;`